# Argument 2 passed to App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::App\Providers\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Post, string given,

Tags: laravel-5.7

Am getting the above error when i try to edit a blog post on my laravel 5.7 App. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

My Post Controller;

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $post = Post::find($id);
    return view('posts.edit')->withPost($post);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Form validation
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'title' =>'required|max:190',
        'category' =>'required|max:190',
        'body' =>'required'
    ));

    //save in db
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $post->title=$request->input('title');
    $post->category=$request->input('category');
    $post->body=Purifier::clean($request->input('body'));
    $post->save();
    Session::flash('success','Blog successfuly updated!');

    return redirect()->route('posts.show',$post->id);
}
```

My AuthServiceProvider;

```
public function registerPostPolicies()
{
  Gate::define('create-post', function($user){
    $user->hasAccess(['create-post']);
  });

  Gate::define('update-post', function($user, Post $post){
    $user->hasAccess(['update-post']) or $user ->id ==$post -> user_id;
  });

  Gate::define('delete-post', function($user, Post $post){
    $user->hasAccess(['delete-post']) or $user ->id ==$post -> user_id;
  });
}
```

I have spent several hours trying to resolve the issue, but i dont seem to be making any progress.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Does this works "->withPost($post);" in edit method ? that's new for me i generally use with() or compact. btw where are you getting error ? while accessing edit method or update method ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro While accessing the update method